# Remove gap/margin from nav bar in BottomSheet Fragment in Android

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I'm using the bottom sheet fragment to display a pop up.
I've used https://stackoverflow.com/a/51329005/5519745 to set the navigation bar color. However in a few devices there is a gap between the navigation bar and the bottom sheet dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have used the same stack overflow solution as you to set a white background on the navigation bar and encountered the same problem.

I solved the issue by updating **setWhiteNavigationBar** *setLayerInsetTop* *metrics.heightPixels* field to a small minus of whatever desired to bring the bottom sheet down a bit.

Hope this helps.

---

**Original**

```
windowBackground.setLayerInsetTop(1, metrics.heightPixels);
```

[image: Original with gap between bottomsheet and navbar]

---

**Amended**

```
windowBackground.setLayerInsetTop(1, metrics.heightPixels - 2);
```

[image]

---